# Best way to return to earlier part of a code in Julia?

Tags: string, julia

I created a pediatric medical dosing calculator in Julia. The program allows the user to enter a patient's weight, dosing frequency, etc. to get a numerical output.

However, once the numerical output is calculated, is there a way I can give the user the option to re-run the program and enter new information? For example, if a doctor wanted to do a new calculation for a different patient they could enter "yes", else they could enter "exit".

What function would be most appropriate to accomplish this?

Comment: Some sort of loop -- `while input is not "exit", do_calculation()`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a infinite `while` loop which you interrupt with `break`.

```
while true
   print("What's your name ? \n"); 
   name = readline()
   println("The name is ", name)
   print("\n\n")
   print("Continue ? [y/n]\n")
   # maybe check if the answer is not "y" or "n"
   answer = readline()
   if answer == "n"
       break
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do something like this:

```
function pmd_calculator()
    # ask data and calculate stuff
    function final_question()
        println("Run program again for new patient? [y|n]")
        answer = readline()
        if answer == "y"
            pmd_calculator()
        elseif answer == "n"
            println("K, bye!")
        else
            println("invalid answer, try again.")
            final_question()
        end
    end
    final_question()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of thing that is often done with a spreadsheet or database in the background.  If you are running this on a laptop rather than as a web app, you could set it up as a Gtk app:

```
using Gtk

function dosecalculator(func::Function, rlabel = "Results")
    wentry, aentry, hentry, qentry = GtkEntry(), GtkEntry(), GtkEntry(), GtkEntry()
    weightunits = [GtkRadioButton("kg")]
    push!(weightunits, GtkRadioButton(weightunits[1], "lb"))
    ageunits = [GtkRadioButton("years")]
    push!(ageunits, GtkRadioButton(ageunits[1], "months"))
    heightunits = [GtkRadioButton("cm")]
    push!(heightunits, GtkRadioButton(heightunits[1], "in"))
    resultbutton = GtkButton("Calculate")
    resultlabel = GtkLabel("0")
    win = GtkWindow("Dose Calculator", 500, 100) |> (GtkFrame() |> (vbox = GtkBox(:v)))
    wbox = GtkButtonBox(:h)
    push!(wbox, GtkLabel("Patient Weight"), wentry, weightunits...)
    abox = GtkButtonBox(:h)
    push!(abox, GtkLabel("Age"), aentry, ageunits...)
    hbox = GtkButtonBox(:h)
    push!(hbox, GtkLabel("Height"), hentry, heightunits...)
    resultbox = GtkButtonBox(:h)
    qbox = GtkButtonBox(:h)
    push!(qbox, GtkLabel("Give medication every: "), qentry, GtkLabel(" hours."))
    set_gtk_property!(qentry, :text, "12")
    push!(resultbox, GtkLabel(rlabel), resultlabel, resultbutton)
    push!(vbox, wbox, abox, hbox, qbox, resultbox)

    function calculate(w)
        wt = parse(Float64, get_gtk_property(wentry, :text, String)) /
            (get_gtk_property(weightunits[1], :active, Bool) ? 1 : 0.393701)
        ht = parse(Float64, get_gtk_property(hentry, :text, String)) *
            (get_gtk_property(heightunits[1], :active, Bool) ? 1 : 2.20462)
        ag = parse(Float64, get_gtk_property(aentry, :text, String)) /
            (get_gtk_property(ageunits[1], :active, Bool) ? 1 : 12)
        result = func(weight = wt, height = ht, age = ag)
        dosagefraction = parse(Float64, get_gtk_property(qentry, :text, String)) / 24
        GAccessor.text(resultlabel, "                      ")
        GAccessor.text(resultlabel, string(result * dosagefraction))
    end

    signal_connect(calculate, resultbutton, :clicked)

    cond = Condition()
    endit(w) = notify(cond)
    signal_connect(endit, win, :destroy)
    showall(win)
    wait(cond)
end

f(; age = 30, weight = 70, height = 200, args...) = age * weight * height

dosecalculator(f)
```

Here, you want the function you pass to the Gtk app to take its arguments in named form (weight = 70.5, etc) and customize the function for the calculation you want to make. (The example I gave just multiplies all together.)